# CLR SQL User Defined type pass list of ID to stored procedure

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net, sqlclr

Many times in projects we pass a list of IDs from UI to stored procedure. Most solutions are based on creating the sql string split functions that creates temporary table and perform the some inner joinr with temp table. e.t.

Did any one have experience in creating the CLR SQL UDT some StringList that we can pass in to the user proc

```
StringList stringList = new StringList();
stringList.Add("ID1");
stringList.Add("ID2");
stringList.Add("ID3");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectDataByIDs");
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("list", SqlDbType.Udt){ Value = stringList});
```

and use in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM DataTable 
WEHRE DataId in @stringList -- or inner join?
```

Please share your wisdom

Comment: Another approach  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure  I like the TVP answer

Comment: Agreed - TVP is the way to go if you're using SQL 2008 or higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This what I made for my case:

```
--declare type
CREATE TYPE StringIDList AS TABLE
(   StringId NVARCHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY )
go
--test function
CERATE PROCEDURE SelectListValue
(   @ids [dbo].[StringIDList] readonly )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM @ids WHERE StringId <> '30'
END
```

C# code

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS2012;Initial
Catalog=db;Integrated Security=true");
conn.Open();

List<SqlDataRecord> records = new List<SqlDataRecord>();
var rec = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("stringid", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 8));
rec.SetValue(0, "10");
records.Add(rec);

rec = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("stringid", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 8));
rec.SetValue(0, "30");
records.Add(rec);

var cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectListValue");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = conn;

var param = new SqlParameter("@ids", SqlDbType.Structured);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
param.TypeName = "StringIDList";
param.Value = records;

cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
}
```

Console outup

```
10
```

Looks pretty straight forward... what do you think?