# Can a table valued parameter to stored procedure have default values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose that I have a two column User Defined Table type

```
CREATE TYPE [Schema].[Type] AS TABLE (
    [Name]         NVARCHAR (100) NULL
    [Value]         int NULL
);
```

Further suppose that I have stored procedure that I pass the table type to

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Schema].[sp_SomeProcedure]
@TVP [Type] READONLY
AS
SELECT 
[Name]
,1 + [Value]
FROM
@TVP
```

Can I default the value of @TVP to be

```
(SELECT 'John', 1)
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/14206591/292060 (related; possible duplicate)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the 'DEFAULT' keyword for the TVP when calling the procedure. That will pass an empty table of the type.

Example - if the TVP is the second parameter passed to a procedure:

```
    Exec myProcedure (intParam, DEFAULT)
```

Comment: You may also simply leave the parameter unspecified to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server does not allow to make a TVP an optional parameter but setting some sort of default value to it, if you have a `TVP` in your procedure you will need to pass a TVP at runtime.

But there is a way around to it, add another parameter to your procedure which decides the behavior of TVP in your procedure.

Mind you in any case you would need to pass a TVP to your procedure at runtime.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Schema].[sp_SomeProcedure]
   @TVP_Default BIT = 1 
  ,@TVP [dbo].[Test_Type] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (
                            [Name]  NVARCHAR(100) NULL
                           ,[Value] int NULL
                           );

-- If @TVP_Default = 1 default values will be populated 
-- else values passed to TVP will be used    
IF (@TVP_Default = 1)
  BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @tempTable([Name] , [Value])
    SELECT 'John' , 1
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @tempTable([Name] , [Value])
    SELECT   [Name]
          ,1 + [Value]
    FROM @TVP
  END

  /*   
        rest of the code

       use @tempTable instead of the TVP in rest of the code
  */

END
```

Comment: Thanks, this isn't exactly what I wanted but it will do. As a replacement of instead of mixing the two tables, I simply use an actual #temptable which I union the TVP and tempTable in the default case or select * into the not default case, then I can reference the one object.