# Why does SQL Server 2008 return two result sets from a proc w/ a TVP when one result set is expected?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Take this Table Type and Proc:

```
CREATE TYPE TwoInts AS TABLE (i1 INT, i2 INT)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE P @ints TwoInts READONLY
AS SELECT * FROM @ints
GO
```

Here is how to run it:

```
DECLARE @ints TwoInts
INSERT INTO @ints(i1, i2) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4)

EXEC P @ints -- returns result set as expected
```

Here is the result, as expected:

[image]

Perfect.

But then if I do this:

```
EXEC P (SELECT * FROM @ints)
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Notice above how now there are two result sets -- one with no rows, and one with the correct number of rows.

**Question:** What causes SQL to return two result sets in this situation?

```
@@Version =
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5538.0 (X64)
Apr  3 2015 14:50:02 
Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it. Duh. It's executing my procedure without any parameters, returning no result set. Then just running my select afterward.

Here is the reason: [Table Value optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206591/table-value-optional-parameter)

Comment: but why it is executing without any parameters first?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli because non are passed in the syntax given, the syntax to pass a parameter is not that given in the question so it is parsed as an exec then a select. In which case it defaults to an empty table for a TVP with no parameter value supplied.

Comment: If that were what it was doing, then I would expect an error message about expected parameters being missing, rather than simply an empty result set.   Unless you did get the message, and just didn't see it because you were looking at the results.

Comment: @TabAlleman table valued parameters are always optional. If you don't pass anything in it uses an empty table. There is no runtime error here.