# How to pass a string array as an optional parameter in a Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a SQL Server Stored Procedure that is returning data correctly. I need to expand this to accept a string array as an optional parameter

Currenty it is run using

```
EXEC vle_sp_getCurrentCourses @Faculty = 'HUM', @CurrentTerm = '121';
```

OR

```
EXEC vle_sp_getCurrentCourses @Faculty = 'HUM', @CurrentTerm = '121', @YearDiff = 2;
```

E.g.

I'd like to pass something like 'SALC,AMBS' using

```
EXEC vle_sp_getCurrentCourses @Faculty = 'HUM', @CurrentTerm = '121', @YearDiff = 2, @Subjects = 'SALC,AMBS';
```

Here is the Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE vle_sp_getCurrentCourses
  @Faculty AS VARCHAR (3),
  @CurrentTerm AS VARCHAR (3),
  @YearDiff AS INT = 1,
WITH EXECUTE AS 'dbo' 
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @SQL_QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX);
  DECLARE @PARAMS NVARCHAR(1000);
    DECLARE @NewTerm VARCHAR(4);
  
    SET @NewTerm = CAST(@CurrentTerm AS INT) + @YearDiff;
  SET @NewTerm = CAST(@NewTerm AS VARCHAR);

    SET @PARAMS = N'@Faculty VARCHAR(3), @CurrentTerm VARCHAR(3), @NewTerm VARCHAR(3)';
  SET @SQL_QUERY = N'
    SELECT mle_destination, REPLACE(mle_id, @CurrentTerm, @NewTerm) as mle_id, mle_type, toenable, available, template_id, start_date_rule, end_date_rule, destination_type
    FROM mle_object
    WHERE
    SUBSTRING(mle_id, 18, 3) LIKE @CurrentTerm
    AND SUBSTRING(mle_id,7,4) IN (SELECT Value FROM @Subjects) OR @Subjects IS NULL)
    AND mle_type = ''COURSE''
    AND (
        @Faculty = ''BMH'' AND SUBSTRING(mle_id, 1, 5) IN (''I3011'',''I3114'',''I3114'',''I3115'',''I3116'',''I2018'',''I3032'',''I3115'',''I3116'',''I3036'',''I3037'',''I3038'',''I3040'',''I3056'',''I3057'',''I3058'',''I3071'',''I3072'',''I3073'',''I3074'',''I3075'',''I3089'',''I3090'',''I3091'',''I3092'',''I3093'',''I3094'',''I3113'',''I3114'',''I3115'',''I3116'',''I3117'')
        OR
        @Faculty = ''HUM'' AND SUBSTRING(mle_id, 1, 5) IN (''I3000'',''I3009'',''I3016'',''I3083'',''I3088'',''I3026'',''I3028'',''I3029'',''I3031'',''I3041'',''I3078'',''I3080'',''I3081'')
        OR
        @Faculty = ''FSE'' and SUBSTRING(mle_id, 1, 5) IN (''I3022'',''I3021'',''I3023'',''I3025'',''I3027'',''I2000'',''I3035'',''I3034'',''I3033'',''I3039'',''I3043'',''I3060'',''I3061'',''I3062'',''I3066'',''I3100'',''I3112'',''I3119'')
    )'

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL_QUERY, @PARAMS, @Faculty = @Faculty, @CurrentTerm = @CurrentTerm, @NewTerm = @NewTerm;

END
```

I've tried create a custom type using

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.SchoolSubject AS TABLE(Subjects NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL)
```

Then declaring

```
@Subject dbo.SchoolSubject(Subject VARCHAR) READONLY = NULL;
```

, but I'm getting a syntax error.

Comment: If you are using SQL 2016 or later (I suggest you add the version-specific tag to your question), you can use `STRING_SPLIT`(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: To declare a tyope you just use the type's name: `DECLARE @VariableName SchemaName.TypeName;`

Comment: This is also missing an opening parentheses for the `OR` conditional expression before `SUBSTRING(mle_id, 7, 4)`

Comment: For an optional table type parameter you don't need ` = NULL` after the parameter, it already defaults to an empty table, so you could call your procedure without the `@subject` parameter and it would work. [This answer should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206591/table-value-optional-parameter)