# Passing array to a SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, arrays, t-sql, ado.net

How can I pass an array variable to a SQL Server stored procedure using C# and insert array values into a whole row?

Thanks in advance.

SQL Server table:

```
ID    | Product | Description
-------------------------------
8A3H  | Soda    | 600ml bottle
```

C# array:

```
string[] info = new string[] {"7J9P", "Soda", "2000ml bottle"};
```

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROC INSERT
    (@INFO_ARRAY ARRAY)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Products VALUES (@INFO_ARRAY)
END
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use multiple parameters or are you just looking for a shortcut?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure?rq=1

Comment: Just looking a shortcut. @DStanley

Comment: You can use a [TVP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Sorry, that's not a simple option in T-SQL.  You could probably get it to work with dynamic sql or table-valued parameters but it would be cleaner and safer to use multiple parameters.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/  Tells it all  And is very efficient

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**In SQL Server 2008 and later**

Create a type in SQL Server like so:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ProductArray 
AS TABLE
(
  ID INT,
  Product NVARCHAR(50),
  Description NVARCHAR(255)
);
```

Alter your procedure in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROC INSERT_SP
@INFO_ARRAY AS dbo.ProductArray READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Products SELECT * FROM @INFO_ARRAY
END
```

Then you'll need to create a `DataTable` object with values to pass in C#:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//Add Columns
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("Product");
dt.Columns.Add("Description");
//Add rows
dt.Rows.Add("7J9P", "Soda", "2000ml bottle");

using (conn)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.INSERT_SP", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter dtparam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INFO_ARRAY", dt);
    dtparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
}
```

Comment: This looks almost identical to the answer in the link I posted above. Did you write this yourself or have you changed that answer?

Comment: I wrote this based on code I wrote a few weeks back, based on an article I found here:  [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/631284/How-to-pass-an-array-to-SQL-SERVER-stored-pro)

Comment: I have an error in the Stored Procedure: "Must declare a scalar variable "@INFO_ARRAY"" @kerbasaurus

Comment: "INFO_ARRAY" is a table, not a scalar, so in your stored proc, INSERT INTO Products VALUES (@INFO_ARRAY) needs to be changed to INSERT INTO Products SELECT * FROM @INFO_ARRAY

Comment: Fix the 2nd to last line to read, `dtparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;`

Comment: What do you do when you have to use `DbType` instead of `SqlDbType`?

Answer (score 2):

here is a way simpler example:

I've been searching through all the examples and answers of how to pass any array to sql server,till i found this [linK](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx), below is how I applied it to my project:

--The following code is going to get an Array as Parameter and insert the values of that
--array into another table

```
Create Procedure Proc1 



@INFO_ARRAY ARRAY nvarchar(max)  //this is the array your going to pass from C# code

AS

    declare @xml xml

    set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@INFO_ARRAY,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

    Insert into Products 
    select 
     t.value('.','varchar(max)')


    from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as a(t)
END
```

Hope you enjoy it