# Dynamically update with stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

We have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test (
    StartDate DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    EndDate DATETIME2 NULL
    Field1 NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Field2 NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    etc.
)
```

If we insert a row the EndDate is always NULL. If it comes to an update we don't really update the existing row but we set the EndDate of it and insert a new one. Assuming there is a stored procedure for insert and update.

```
DECLARE @newStartDate DATETIME2
SELECT @newStartDate = GETDATE()

UPDATE dbo.Test SET (EndDate = @newStartDate) WHERE StartDate = @someDate

INSERT INTO dbo.Test (StartDate, EndDate, Field1, Field2) 
     SELECT @newStartDate, NULL, Field1, Field2 
       FROM dbo.Test where StartDate = @someDate AND EndDate = @newStartDate
```

It can happen that we need to set other start/insert values than the old ones. That can be done as follows.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (StartDate, EndDate, Field1, Field2) 
    SELECT @newStartDate, NULL, @parameter, Field2 
      FROM dbo.Test where StartDate = @someDate AND EndDate = @newStartDate
```

The main problem is now that the real table contains more than 100 columns and the above approach would work but is very error prone.

I'm looking for a dynamic approach where the insert statement dynamically takes the parameter value if it exists.

In C# I would do something like this. `existing` would be a `Dictionary` containing every column and `overrides` are the not default values that needs to be changed.

```
var existing= ..."SELECT TOP 1 * from dbo.Test"
foreach (var changeParameter in overrides)
     existing[changeParameter.Key] = changeParameter.Value;
```

In `existing` are now all values stored as they should be for the insert. Therefore I can build a new insert statement.

Is this approach somehow possible on the database? I don't want to load all data rows just to write it back right away. I would rather do everything directly on the database.

Comment: _"I'm looking for a dynamic approach where the insert statement dynamically takes the parameter value"_ - why not just build the insert SQL dynamically?

Comment: @stuartd Sure, but how can I do that? I wanna build the insert statement on the database. How can I decide whether I can take parameter '@field1' or Field1 from the old row dynamically?

Comment: Am I correct that you want sql script that will have `insert (cols) values (vals)` where cols __list__ and __vals__ list will contain some array of values that was passed from somewhere else? Is this your dynamic part? Long list of columns that may differ?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Yes, the list with passed parameter could be long, the main goal is to pick either the value from the parameter, if it's provided, or select it from the previous row.

Comment: @Dani So set of params has constant number of elements but some of them are nulls (and this insert is placed likely within stored proc) **or**  _number of elements_ passed varies and `insert` script is an ad-hoc query build on client side?

Comment: @IvanStarostin number of elements passed varies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for a dynamic approach where the insert statement
>   dynamically takes the parameter value if it exists.

This is the way I have always done this:

Make the parameter optional by giving it a default value of NULL.

Then `COALESCE` the parameter with the field you want to use if no parameter value was supplied:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (StartDate, EndDate, Field1, Field2) 
    SELECT @newStartDate, NULL, COALESCE(@parameter,Field1), Field2 
      FROM dbo.Test where StartDate = @someDate AND EndDate = @newStartDate
```

Simple as that.

EDIT:

If you use a Table Valued Parameter, and JOIN to it, then your `COALESCE` looks like either this, if you have 1 column per field in the TVP:

```
COALESCE(tvp.Field1, Test.Field1)
```

Or if you passed the TVP as a vertical table of FieldName, FieldValue pairs, then you would have to use either a CASE expression or Subquery like this:

```
COALESCE((SELECT FieldValue FROM TVP WHERE FieldName='Field1'),Field1)
```

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is that my table has over 270 columns, that would be quite a parameter list...

Comment: In that case, you can pass a table-valued parameter, JOIN to it, and use the same technique.

Comment: How do you mean "JOIN"? I think that I don't understand it right. Do you have an example?

Comment: JOINing tables is a basic SQL operation that is too broad to teach in a SO answer.   If you google `SQL JOIN Tutorial` you will find plenty of examples.

Comment: I know what JOIN's are but I don't get the point how joining a table-valued parameter solves my problem.

Comment: Added explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question :

> I'm looking for a dynamic approach where the insert statement
>   dynamically takes the parameter value if it exists. Is this approach
>   somehow possible on the database?

1. To get T-SQL dynamism in SQL server you will have to use **[sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)**, more information :

   [Execute Dynamic SQL commands in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)
2. You will have to pass field parameters as some kind of array. There are couple of ways, here is one way :

   [Passing array to a SQL Server Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24636916/3728624)
3. Your solution will involve use of [CURSOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) to build dynamic Sql query, see example :

   [SQL Server Cursor Example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/)

Comment: Please see my comment above

Comment: You have answered it in C# example by mentioning key/value pair. What you will have to pass to Stored Procedure field and value combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how c# parses query params but you can do something like this:

```
var sql = "
declare @param1 int = :param1,
  @param2 int = :param2,
  @param3 date = :param3,
  @somedate datetime = :somedate,
  @newstartdate datetime = :newstartdate,
  ...


insert into dbo.Test (...full list of columns)
select isnull(@param1, field1), isnull(@param2, field2), ...and so on
from dbo.Test
where StartDate = @someDate AND EndDate = @newStartDate
"
```

And then assign values or NULL to all the params. `ISNULL` will do the thing and you'll have *new value* or *old value* if new is NULL. But some tricks would be required to place exactly null.

or

you have to build whole query at runtime on client-side

or

pass TVP with param names and values as @TabAlleman suggested and check this table for existence of param of the same name as specific column int your table. And then proceed with `ISNULL` or something to choose whether to leave existing value or take from TVP passed.