# MVC 4 - Insert list/array from Controller to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 C# Razor view and MS SQL Server. I need to insert a list/array value from controller to sql server. I am passing values from view to controller and getting the values in controller.

My data structures are -

```
{sid: "101", m1Qty: "1", m2Qty: "3", m3Qty: ""}
{sid: "102", m1Qty: "5", m2Qty: "6", m3Qty: ""}
{sid: "103", m1Qty: "8", m2Qty: "0", m3Qty: ""}
```

Above data needed to insert my table (tbl_monthqty) in the below order. `ID` auto generated -

```
ID  SID     MonthID   mQty
1   101        1       1 
2   102        1       5
3   103        1       8
4   101        2       3
5   102        2       6
```

If any value `null` or `0`, need to ignore

MonthID is for example - `m1Qty = 1, m2Qty = 2, m3Qty = 3`

My controller (C#) is -

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveQty(IList<AllQty> model)
{
    var list = new [] { model };
    var count = list.Count();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("SID");
    dt.Columns.Add("MonthID");
    dt.Columns.Add("mQty");

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        //dt.Rows.Add();
        // Not sure what I will do here
    }

    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

My class is -

```
public class AllQty
{
    public int SID { get; set; }
    public int MonthID { get; set; }
    public int mQty { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the list value in controller but not sure how I will insert those list/array values in my table. I have tried few asked questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636669/passing-array-to-a-sql-server-stored-procedure) but did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fill a datatable with List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076034/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fill a datatable with List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076034/how-to-fill-a-datatable-with-listt)

Comment: @adiga, my data structure is different from the above question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Bulk Copy/Insert in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841000/sql-bulk-copy-insert-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @AryanFirouzyan, please check my data structures first

Comment: if you use entity framework, it creates the model or data structure. It doesn't matter if you have different data structure. You can insert values the same way.

Comment: @AryanFirouzyan, I don't want to use entity framework, could you please help me how I will add data in my table using the data I am getting

Comment: Do you have any class to represent the data structure. So we can convert json data to list of objects?

Comment: According to the question, your intention is to convert a list to `datatable`. Of course, the classes are different. SO is not a code writing service. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: @AryanFirouzyan, I have updated my question, where I added the class

Comment: @adiga, I tried to convert but did not able to workout

Comment: What did not work out? You need to change the properties from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19076205/3082296) to that of your class.

Comment: @adiga, how I will add m1Qty, m2Qty, m3Qty value to mQty column because all in one row, also I am not much experienced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create data model that represent json data structure:

```csharp
public class FirstModel
  {
    public int SID;
    public string m1Qty;
    public string m2Qty;
    public string m3Qty;
  }
```

Then data model that you want to store the data:

```csharp
public class AllQty
  {
    public int SID { get; set; }
    public int MonthID { get; set; }
    public int mQty { get; set; }
  }
```

Then convert the json to list of FirstModel objects (I assume you already did it), and finally convert data in List to List :

```
        List<FirstModel> qtYs = new List<FirstModel>();
        List<AllQty> allQties = new List<AllQty>();
        foreach (FirstModel item in qtYs)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.m1Qty))
            {
                AllQty allQty = new AllQty
                {
                    MonthID = 1,
                    mQty = int.Parse(item.m1Qty),
                    SID = item.SID
                };
                allQties.Add(allQty);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.m2Qty))
            {
                AllQty allQty = new AllQty
                {
                    MonthID = 2,
                    mQty = int.Parse(item.m1Qty),
                    SID = item.SID
                };
                allQties.Add(allQty);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.m3Qty))
            {
                AllQty allQty = new AllQty
                {
                    MonthID = 3,
                    mQty = int.Parse(item.m1Qty),
                    SID = item.SID
                };
                allQties.Add(allQty);
            }
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("SID");
        dt.Columns.Add("MonthID");
        dt.Columns.Add("mQty");

        foreach (AllQty allQty in allQties)
        {
            var row = dt.NewRow();

            row["SID"] = allQty.SID;
            row["MonthID"] = allQty.MonthID;
            row["mQty"] = allQty.mQty;

            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```