# How to pass array parameter to stored procedure in my case without changing C# code?

Tags: sql, arrays, stored-procedures

I have to pass the multivalue parameter to a stored procedure. The datatype which is passing from C# code is `string[]`.

This is my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spRecords
    @Department VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        ItemDetails,
        Total,
        Department
    FROM
        ItemRecords
    WHERE
        (Department.Name IN (@Department) OR @Department IS NULL)
END
```

I get the following error message

> Cannot convert from string[] to string

I saw this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636669/passing-array-to-a-sql-server-stored-procedure?lq=1) second answer to declare variable like `@INFO_ARRAY ARRAY nvarchar(max)`. But I don't know how I should apply that in my case

**Update**

I don't want to change any code from C#. I am using one tool that will directly pass `string[]` array parameter like datasource

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: @Gserg can you check my update. And please remove duplicate. I am trying this since two days

Comment: It's not about what you want to do, it's about what is possible to do, and that is what the duplicate question shows. You don't sent `string[]` to an SQL Server database because there is no corresponding server data type.

Comment: @GSerg Can we pass parameter as string like `Fruits,Vegetables,IceCream` and then convert into `'Fruits','Vegetables','IceCream'` set it to @department?