# Pass integer array to the SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Well this well answered question however I can't get it right for me. What I am trying to do call a stored procedure from .NET Core project using Entity Framework with some parameters. One of those parameter should be array (which I consider table type in SQL Server by create a custom table data type) type. I followed [this Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24636916/8112522). But got an error when I tried to execute my SQL command.

Here is my code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));

foreach (var section in model.VMSectionIds) //model.VMSectionIds contains set of integers
{
    dt.Rows.Add(section);
}
```

and finally I call stored procedure like this:

```
var sectiolist = new SqlParameter("@Sections", SqlDbType.Structured)
            {
                TypeName = "[dbo].[SectionList]",
                Value = dt
            };
_db.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC [SP_GenerateRegularEmployeeSalary] "+mastermodel.ID+","+ fromdate + "," + todate + ",1," + sectiolist + ""); //don't worry I took care of SQL injection for others parameter
```

But this execution throws an exception

> SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@Sections"

I can't figure it out where exact problem is. Here call of stored procedure (with some static test parameter) from SQL for clear understanding of my stored procedure call mechanism:

```
DECLARE @data [SectionList]
INSERT @data (Id) VALUES (2, 3)

EXEC [SP_GenerateRegularEmployeeSalary] 2,'20190401','20190430','1',@data
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks that you are using the `ExecuteSqlCommand` incorrectly. Try this way and don't use string concatenation in your code to avoid SQL Injection attacks in your application. Read more about it [here](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/).

Also put the correct expected parameter names from the stored procedure: `SP_GenerateRegularEmployeeSalary`.

**Option 1**

```
_db.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC [SP_GenerateRegularEmployeeSalary] @ID, @FromDate, @ToDate, @Flag, @Sections", 
   new SqlParameter("@ID", mastermodel.ID),
   new SqlParameter("@FromDate", fromdate),
   new SqlParameter("@ToDate", todate),
   new SqlParameter("@Flag", 1),
   new SqlParameter("@Sections", sectiolist));
```

**Option 2**

```
_db.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC [SP_GenerateRegularEmployeeSalary] @ID = {0}, @FromDate = {1}, @ToDate = {2}, @Flag = 1, @Sections = {4}", mastermodel.ID, fromdate, todate, sectiolist);
```

Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) documentation about this method.

Answer (score 1):

he using ExecuteSqlCommand incorrectly. he should not used string concatenation to avoid SQL Injection attacks in th application

_db.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC SP_GenerateRegularEmployeeSalary @YOUR_PARAM_ON_STOREPROCEDURE", sectiolist);

Comment: Any explanation what this approach does differently, and why this solves the problem?

Comment: he using ExecuteSqlCommand incorrectly. he should not used  string concatenation to avoid SQL Injection attacks in th application

Comment: Put that explanation in your answer! (I totally agree with it, btw)

Comment: Thanks, I got it now but I can only one as correct answer, hopefully you provide little bit explanation with answer for make it accepted one. :)