# Passing a parameter as list in linq (LINQ TO ENTITIES EF6)?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, parameters

I am calling a stored procedure (PS_StatistiqueEsc) via LINQ, and in the stored procedure i pass 3 parameters start,end and engin (see the code at bottom).

```
using (var escEnts = new escEntities()) {
var query = escEnts.PS_StatistiqueEsc(Convert.ToDateTime(start),
Convert.ToDateTime(end), engin).ToList();
}
```

so far so good.

my questions is how can i pass a 4th parameter as a list like (see the code at bottom) or an XML  as a parameter:

For Example :

```
List<int> listToPassInSP = new List<int>();
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
list.Add(7);

using (var escEnts = new escEntities()) {
var query = escEnts.PS_StatistiqueEsc(Convert.ToDateTime(start), Convert.ToDateTime(end), engin, listToPassInSP).ToList();
}
```

Actually the stored procedure accept only 3 parameters ? I am going to changed change my sp which is going to  accept a 4th parameter.

The actual SP signature is :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PS_StatistiqueEsc] 
    @dateDebut datetime,
    @dateFin datetime,
    @EnginName varchar(250)     
AS
```

But will be changed like this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PS_StatistiqueEsc] 
    @dateDebut datetime,
    @dateFin datetime,
    @EnginName varchar(250),
    @listToPassInSP ???? (i don't know how to declare a variable like a list)
AS
```

Just want to pass a list to a SP and and the SP must accept a list. How can i do ?

Comment: 4th parameter of what, where? Can you clarify a bit? Show the desired usage scenario if it is difficult to describe it verbally.

Comment: thanks for your help, just came to modify my question... i want to pass a list or xml as a parameter in stored procedure.

Comment: If `PS_StatistiqueEsc` stored procedure accepts only 3 parameters, than how do you want to force it to accept the fourth? What is the signature of the `PS_StatistiqueEsc` and how should it handle the 4th param? Or do you mean that you want to add some predefined result set into the data returned by `PS_StatistiqueEsc`?

Comment: Hi, i reformulated my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure describes how to declare such a stored procedure in SQL (there are both answers that use XML and that directly use List). I never used such Stored Procedures with EF, but I think that the code generated by EF designer for this procedure will be quite straightforward and easy to use.