# How to set a temp table variable from a Function that returns TABLE?

Tags: sql-server

I Have a UDF that returns a TABLE.

In my SP i define a temp table variable:

```
declare @t table ([ID] uniqueidentifier)
```

How do I set `@t = MyDF`?

Only method that works is:

```
INSERT INTO @t SELECT * FROM dbo.MyUDF(@List)
```

This **does not** work:

```
SELECT * INTO @t FROM dbo.MyUDF(@List) -- <- This is just a note, and NOT the question
```

**My Question:** Can't I just somehow assign `select @t = dbo.MyUDF`?
Is there any other way to **directlly** assign the UDF result TABLE to the temp variable other than actually `"INSERT INTO"`/`"SELECT INTO"`

EDIT: I know I can reference `dbo.MyUDF()` in my query directly without using a temp table variable. but since I need to reference this a few times in my SP, I prefer to work with a local variable which will be assigned only once, and not process `dbo.MyUDF()` each time I reference it.

My UDF is very much the same as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11105413/3933402 (`SplitInts` - only mine returns uniqueidentifier)

Comment: No, to get data into your table variable, you're going to have to insert it. Why is this a problem?

Comment: The other option, of course, is to not use a table variable in the first place, and just reference dbo.MyUDF() in your query directly.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, b/c the additional INSERT costs performance. I thought since the UDF already returns a TABLE object I could reference it. I need to reference `dbo.MyUDF()` (@t) a few times in that SP. so the whole process in that UDF will run again and again when I reference it (? - not sure)

Comment: Why do you think SELECT INTO or SELECT @t = wouldn't incur the same performance "problem"? Have you validated that any of this is actually a problem, or are you prematurely optimizing? Instead of worrying about the cost of inserting into a table variable or how you're going to reference the UDF in your query, maybe you should focus on optimizing the UDF itself - e.g. make sure it is schemabinding, is an inline table-valued UDF and not a multi-statement one, and that the work really needs to be done by a UDF in the first place...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I actually need to impliment this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11105413/3933402 (SplitInts). It's your answer ("focus on optimizing the UDF itself") :) And my question was rather simple: is there any other way to assign the result TABLE to the temp variable other than actually "INSERT INTO"

Answer (score -1):

could you try 
SELECT * INTO #t FROM dbo.MyUDF(@List)