# Variable in comma separated in the IN CLAUSE of SP of DB2 for Z/OS

Tags: db2

I have a SP in which I have a In clause like mentioned below 
value1 is a Int,Variable1 is varchar
Suppose SP started
Variable1=(value1,value2,value3)--getting from another  table

Select * from tableA where Column1 in (Variable1).

The just above statement is not working ,needed a work around for this ,Please help

Comment: You may find some help in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246620/pass-array-as-parameter-in-db2-stored-procedure  
Another trick would be to pass an XML list and use `XMLTABLE` to perform a `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example of using an XML list to select an arbitrary number of values:

```
SELECT * FROM "tableA"
WHERE "Column1" IN (
SELECT * FROM
XMLTABLE('$X/set/row' PASSING XMLPARSE('
<set>
<row item="1"/>
<row item="2"/>
<row item="3"/>
<!-- add as many "row" as you need here -->
</set>
')
AS "X"
COLUMNS 
"item" INT PATH '@item'
) AS X
)
```

Then you can parameterize the query, where `?` is a parameter of type `XML`

```
SELECT * FROM "tableA"
WHERE "Column1" IN (
  SELECT * FROM 
  XMLTABLE('$X/set/row' PASSING ? AS "X" COLUMNS "item" INT PATH '@item') AS X
)
```