# String of text search

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following string.

> car, bus, bike, house

I would like to split these into individual strings and use them in a where clause so it would like this:

```
SELECT [text]
FROM [table]
WHERE
text LIKE 'bus'
or text LIKE 'car'
or text LIKE 'bike'
or text LIKE 'house'
```

How would you go through the original string and split them out into individual substrings. The original text string is being passed as variable from a GUI. So far we have this

```
REPLACE(LEFT('%BIKE, BUS, HOUSE%',CHARINDEX(',','%BIKE, BUS, HOUSE%')),',','%'),
REPLACE(SUBSTRING('%BIKE, BUS, HOUSE%',CHARINDEX(',','%LADDER, BA%'),LEN('%BIKE, BUS, HOUSE%')),',','%'),
```

But that only brings back a substring  before the first comma and keeps everything after. eg 'bike' and 'car, bus, house'.

Any ideas?

Comment: what database server are you using? Is it SQL Server?

Comment: Is it an option to do this in a programming language? (PHP, Python, etc.)

Comment: yes SQL Server 2008r2

Comment: Do you actually want `LIKE 'bus'` or do you really want `LIKE '%bus%'`?

Comment: This is trivial in linq and there are dozens of answers out there on how to do it.

Comment: you should have a look at CONTAINS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

Comment: Yeah with % if possible

Comment: How about NOT passing a delimited string?  Pass the parameters individually, or [as an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure).

Comment: http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split a string so I can access item x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Comment: If you do go the split route, you should change your sql to compare against `','+[text]+','`, and then search for things like `'%,bike,%'`, otherwise, searching for `"%bike%"` will return "motorbike" as a match.

Comment: @hatchet If the `[text]` field is also a delimited list then yes, otherwise that's not necessary.

Comment: Search for "convert CSV to table SQL server" and look at some of the results that come up. You can do a regular join on the table then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ with the PredicateBuilder (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

(Sample -- I had a table of ZipCodes handy)

```
var codes = "77,88,99".Split(',');

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<ZipCodes>();
foreach(var c in codes)
    predicate = predicate.Or(z=>z.ZipCode.Contains(c));

var answer = this.ZipCodes.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XML functionality to turn your string into an array, then simply `JOIN` with wildcards:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = 'car, bus, bike, house'
;WITH cte AS (SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) AS Txt    
              FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@string, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS DATA
              ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))
SELECT DISTINCT [text]
FROM [table] a
JOIN cte b
  ON a.[text] LIKE '%'+b.Txt+'%'
```

Ideally you'd pass your array into a table variable and just have to run the `JOIN` at the bottom.

Comment: I do a ton of ETL work and I use this function daily.