# Insert list of tree columns into SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table `Zone` that contains these columns:

```
ID
Name
Province_Id
City_Id
```

I want to pass a list of 3 columns and insert them into that table with a SQL Server stored procedure.

Like this

```
Name       'a,b,c,d'
Province_Id 1,2,3,4
City_Id     1,2,3,4
```

I write this procedure but this procedure works only for one column

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateZone]
    @Name                  NVARCHAR(50),
    @BuildingProvince_Id   INT,
    @BuildingCity_Id       INT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @xml xml;   

        SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@Name,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)

        INSERT INTO ZoneCategory
            SELECT  N.value('.', 'varchar(100)') as value 
            FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)

        SELECT 100
    END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    EXEC InsertSQLError
        SELECT -100 as Error
END CATCH
END
```

How can I change it to insert values for 3 columns?

Or create a procedure for this scenario?

I want insert values for 3 columns with comma

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split function equivalent in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-t-sql)

Comment: Your input parameter Province_Id and City_ID both INT, how do you assign multiple value to them?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achived this is by using String_Split function introduced in Swl Server if i m not wrong in 2016:

```
CREATE or alter PROCEDURE CreateZone
    @Names NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Province_Ids NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @City_Ids NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @NameTable TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Name NVARCHAR(100));
        DECLARE @ProvinceTable TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Province_Id INT);
        DECLARE @CityTable TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), City_Id INT);

        INSERT INTO @NameTable (Name)
        SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Names, ',');

        INSERT INTO @ProvinceTable (Province_Id)
        SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Province_Ids, ',');

        INSERT INTO @CityTable (City_Id)
        SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@City_Ids, ',');

        INSERT INTO Zone (Name, Province_Id, City_Id)
        SELECT NT.Name, PT.Province_Id, CT.City_Id
        FROM @NameTable NT
        JOIN @ProvinceTable PT ON NT.ID = PT.ID
        JOIN @CityTable CT ON NT.ID = CT.ID;

        SELECT 100 AS ResultCode;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT -100 AS ResultCode; 
    END CATCH
END

EXEC CreateZone @Names = 'a,b,c,d', @Province_Ids = '1,2,3,4', @City_Ids = '1,2,3,4';
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

What you're attempting to do is pass an array (well, multiple arrays) as input parameters to a stored procedure.

With that understanding, rather than reword / plagiarize what is already an excellent answer, I'll just point you at this...

[How to pass an array into a SQL Server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure)

Comment: Downvotes without comment are not helpful to anyone.