# SQL Server : is it possible to restrict a where clause to specific values in a pre-declared list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I need to run a simple query against a purchase invoices table to sum the value of a subset of suppliers invoices. Normally this would be a simple case of the following pseudo query;

```
Select Sum(invoiceTotal) 
From PurchaseInvoices
Where ContactId = x
```

The problem that I have is that the particular suppliers that I'm after are randomly distributed throughout the contacts table so I can't simply amend the where clause to say `Between x and y` as it would draw in records I don't want.

If for argument's sake I need to sum the values of contacts a,b,c,g,j,k,s and u is there a way to define a list of contacts at the outset of a SQL query and then simply restrict the where clause to `ContactId`'s that fall within that list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [IN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) clause to provide a list or sub-query that returns the list.

```
Select Sum(invoiceTotal) From PurchaseInvoices
Where ContactId in (x, y, z)
```

Syntax

```
test_expression [ NOT ] IN   
( subquery | expression [ ,...n ]  
)
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of the blindingly obvious.  I'm clearly too tired.  Will mark as correct in a few minutes when the system allows me to.

Comment: You are welcome, no worries sometime we miss the obvious.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest could this be parameterised and used in a stored procedure (in other word Passing in a list of integers to be referred to in the IN part of the Where clause)?

Comment: Yes, probably this would help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure

Comment: Thanks, a very useful link.