# SQL Server stored procedure parameter type array C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I have problem with array parameter in a stored procedure.

My code:

```
var command = "DECLARE  @return_value int EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[GetEmployeeData]  @EmployeeId, @StartTime, @StopTime";

SqlDataAdapter tableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command, cnn);

// Set SQL Server parameters
tableAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartTime", DateTime.Parse(dtpRepEmFrom.Text)));
tableAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StopTime", DateTime.Parse(dtpRepEmTo.Text)));
tableAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmployeeId", keyList.ToArray()));

var dataTable = new DataTable();

// Get data
tableAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

`keylist` is an array of `integer` (and `EmployeeId` is `int` type in database).

I get an error when I fill the dataTable:

> No mapping exists from object type `System.Int32[]` to a known managed provider native type.

Please help me how I add array into parameter.

Comment: Why don't you pass an `empoyeeId` and you pass an array? This doesn't make sence. I refer to this `keyList.ToArray()`. Does you stored procedure returns data for an employee or of a list of employees? In other words, what's the type of `@EmployeeId` parameter? I

Comment: Stored procedure return table with the manufactured products for the group of Employees (EmployeeId is int type)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure