# What is the equivalent passing array int to stored procedure .net 4.6 code for .net core?

Tags: stored-procedures, .net-core, table-valued-parameters

So this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure), shows how to pass an int array to stored procedure.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.EmployeeList
AS TABLE
(
  EmployeeID INT
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DoSomethingWithEmployees
  @List AS dbo.EmployeeList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT EmployeeID FROM @List; 
END
GO
```

and c# Code:

```
DataTable tvp = new DataTable();
// define / populate DataTable from your List here

using (conn)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.DoSomethingWithEmployees", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter tvparam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@List", tvp);
    tvparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    // execute query, consume results, etc. here
}
```

But since .net core does not support datatable, what would be the equivalent code for .net core? Especially adding tvp variable as a parameter in AddWithValue method and also the last line of code which is tvparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured?

**Edit**

So I have this stored procedure that takes three parameters. @StudentIds is an int array.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE stp_Student

@Name nvarchar(450), 
@StudentIds tvp_ArrayInt READONLY,  
@StartDate date

AS

blah blah 

//returns student summary
SELECT  stu.StudentId, 
        stu.StudentName, 
        CASE WHEN (COUNT(DISTINCT course.Id) IS NOT NULL) THEN COUNT(DISTINCT course.Id) ELSE 0 END AS CourseCount, 
        CASE WHEN (SUM(course.TotalCourses) IS NOT NULL) THEN SUM(course.TotalCourses) ELSE 0 END AS TotalCourses, 
        CASE WHEN (SUM(course.Hours) IS NOT NULL) THEN SUM(course.Hours) ELSE 0 END AS Hours
FROM    #TempStudent AS #Temp
```

and based on your recommendation, I tried to do it in controller:

```
public ActionResult Submit(string name, int[] studentIds, DateTime startDate)
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"CREATE TYPE dbo_ArrayInt AS TABLE (intValue Int);");

    var tvp = new TableValuedParameterBuilder("dbo_ArrayInt", new SqlMetaData("intValue", SqlDbType.Int))
            .AddRow(1)
            .AddRow(2)
            .CreateParameter("StudentIds");

    //But here, I'm not sure how to use tvp variable appropriately
     var query = _context.Set<StudentModel>().FromSql("dbo.stp_Student @Name = {0}, @StudentIds = {1}, @StartDate = {2}"
            , name, studentIds, startDate).ToList();
```

Entity for mapping the result:

```
public class StudentModel
{  
    [Key]
    public long RowId { get; set; }   
    public int StudentId { get; set; }    
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int CourseCount { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "Money")]
    public decimal TotalCourses { get; set; }
    public double Hours { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete, self contained example on .net core:

**SCHEMA**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Students (
    StudentId int NOT NULL,
    StudentName varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TYPE dbo.ArrayInt
AS TABLE
(
  intValue INT
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.stp_Student
    @Name nvarchar(450), 
    @StudentIds dbo.ArrayInt READONLY,  
    @StartDate date
AS
    SELECT  
        StudentId, 
        StudentName, 
        3 AS CourseCount, 
        6 AS TotalCourses, 
        9 AS [Hours]
    FROM
        dbo.Students A
        JOIN @StudentIds B ON A.StudentId = B.intValue
```

**CODE**

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace StackOverflow.TpvConsole
{
    public class Program
    {
        private const String SqlConnetionString = @"Server={Server};Database={Database};User={User};Password={Password};";

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            var model = new List<StudentModel>();

            var parameter = new SqlParameter("StudentIds", SqlDbType.Structured)
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                TypeName = "dbo.ArrayInt"
            };

            var items = new List<SqlDataRecord>();

            //just a quick loop to add three student ids
            for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            {
                var rec = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("intValue", SqlDbType.Int));
                rec.SetInt32(0, i);
                items.Add(rec);
            }

            parameter.Value = items;

            using (var db = new SqlConnection(SqlConnetionString))
            {
                var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.stp_Student", db) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure};

                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", "Student Name"));
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("StartDate", new DateTime(2016, 8, 1)));

                db.Open();

                var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    model.Add(new StudentModel
                    {
                        StudentId = reader.GetInt32(0),
                        StudentName = reader.GetString(1),
                        CourseCount = reader.GetInt32(2),
                        TotalCourses = reader.GetInt32(3),
                        Hours = reader.GetInt32(4)
                    });
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in model)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.StudentId}: {item.StudentName}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class StudentModel
        {
            [Key]
            public Int64 RowId { get; set; }
            public Int32 StudentId { get; set; }
            public String StudentName { get; set; }
            public Int32 CourseCount { get; set; }
            [Column(TypeName = "Money")]
            public Decimal TotalCourses { get; set; }
            public Double Hours { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! travis

Answer (score 0):

These are called Table Value Parameters.

[According](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3115#issuecomment-253644223) to a member of the Entity Framework team, you can use a `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` in place of a `DataTable`. A fully functional gist [has been posted](https://gist.github.com/divega/f0f88bf16f35641239cfd9bc534e8d7c).