# DBType in C# for a generic list in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldbtype, dbtype

I am trying to pass a parameter to my query and this parameter value is a list like `('a','b')`. What should be the `dbtype` in this case?

I tried with `dbtype.object` but query returns empty rows.
Can anyone help me with my approach?

Thanks!

Comment: IS it possible to include the code that you are using? how the query looks like and what is the type of that column?

Comment: Why don't you just pass a string 'a,b' as a parameter? Then in your sql, split that parameter to a temp table.

Comment: Add the codes what you have tried so far and define where you are passing the db parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an array into a SQL Server stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure)

Comment: Sql server does not support lists or arreys. For this kind of data, you should use a table valued parameter.

Comment: Query looks like this :SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM [Views].[vw_name] WHERE [Views].[vw_name].[Id] IN ('a','b'). These  a and b can be anything in my scenario like a guid, int, string. I want to pass this comma separated list as sqlparam to my query. Don't want any temp table as the dataset is huge in my scenario which i don't want to keep in memory.

Comment: @lmakkar you can't. To pass a list of values you need to use a table-valued type that will be passed as a DataTable