# SQL Server stored procedure for dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

I need a procedure for below dynamic query. In that procedure, `f_id` and `value` are input parameters. `f_id` and `value` are collections of values.

For example

```
f_id=1780
value=ABC
f_id=22483
value=`sasdfa`
f_id=3334
value=soap
```

So in the below query and exits part will be added dynamically depends on the count of `f_id` and `value`.

```
select distinct 
    v1.entity_id 
from 
    values v1 
inner join 
    listings l on v1.entity_id = l.entity_id   
where 
    l.c_id = 83  
    and exists (select 1 from values v2 
                where v1.entity_id = v2.entity_id 
                  and v2.f_id = 1780 and (value = ABC)) 
    and exists (select 1 from values v3 
                where v1.entity_id = v3.entity_id  
                  and v3.field_id = 22483 and (value = sasdfa)) 
    and exists (select 1 from values v4 
                where v1.entity_id = v4.entity_id   
                  and v4.field_id = 3334 and (value = soap)) 
    and exists (select 1 from values v5 
                where v1.entity_id = v5.entity_id  
                  and v5.field_id = 3433 and (value=paste)) 
order by 
    l.id desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a stored procedure that has the SQL you have provided in your question as a SQL String with parameters and the use the EXEC statement to execute the SQL string.

Below is the example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_dynamic_sql
(   @f_id AS INT,
    @value AS NVARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(2000);

    SET @SQL
        =      ('
SELECT distinct 
    v1.entity_id 
from 
    values v1 
inner join 
    listings l on v1.entity_id = l.entity_id   
where 
    l.c_id = 83  
    and exists (select 1 from values v2 
                where v1.entity_id = v2.entity_id 
                  and v2.f_id = ''' + @f_id + ''' and (value = ''' + @value
                + ''')) 
    and exists (select 1 from values v3 
                where v1.entity_id = v3.entity_id  
                  and v3.field_id = 22483 and (value = '''+@value
                + ''')) 
    and exists (select 1 from values v4 
                where v1.entity_id = v4.entity_id   
                  and v4.field_id = 3334 and (value = '''+@value
                + ''')) 
    and exists (select 1 from values v5 
                where v1.entity_id = v5.entity_id  
                  and v5.field_id = 3433 and (value='''+@value+''')) 
order by 
    l.id desc'''
               );
    EXEC (@SQL);
END;
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is the link in stackoverflow community.
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure)
[Link 2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113458/TSQL-Passing-array-list-set-to-stored-procedure-MS)

If you are not able to make it, let me know. I will help you.

Comment: Input Parameters(f_id,value) accepts more then one values.(Like array)

More then one input values will be passed to this parameters(f_id,value).Like array of values.

Sample Inputs

f_id=1780
value='abc'

f_id=22483
value='xyz'

f_id=3334
value='soap'

f_id=3433
value='paste'

etc.....

In the above query 

and exists  (select 1 from values v5 where v1.entity_id = v5.entity_id  and v5.field_id=3433 and( value='paste' )) 

and exists part of sub query will not be fixed.it will be added depends on the count of input parameters.

Comment: From where you will be passing the values to the stored procedure? Is it from a web page or from another table?

Comment: it is from web page.Asp.net is front end.

Comment: it is from web page.Asp.net is front end.This stored procedure is used for filter application. Filtering the records based on F_id and Value.F_id is the id of column name(like Name,Location....).All column name having id in the table.Value is value of column name (like Raja,USA,)(KUMAR,Mumbai).So more then one i/p parameters will come to procedure.Using this I/P parameters we have to select entity_id.

Comment: I have added links that can help you in my answer.

Comment: Please provide link.Shall we use Table valued parameters for this case?.U have any idea or examples for TVP in this case?

Comment: I have added the link under edit 2. I am currently travelling. So will not be able to read your post immediately.

Comment: Thank you.Now i am using table valued parameters for this case.

Comment: how to mark as correct.Link 1 and Link 2 is helpful.

Comment: You cannot mark as correct for those two links. The links are contained on my answer hence you can mark my answer as correct by clicking on the tick mark. Along with this, click on the link and up vote those answers. This will help them.