# Why conversion issue occurs

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

What is wrong with the query? I am trying to convert the `int` to `varchar`:

```
DELETE FROM CM_OfflineMessages 
WHERE CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ID)) IN ('1,2,3')
```

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2,3' to data type int.

Edit:

I have edited the query

```
[dbo].[CM_DeleteOfflineMessageByID] (@ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
  DELETE FROM CM_OfflineMessages
  WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ID) IN (@ID)
```

However no compile time issue, but the data is not getting purged.

```
exec [dbo].[CM_DeleteOfflineMessageByID] @ID = N'''10'',''11'',''12'''
```

Comment: You are converting to INT :  CONVERT(INT,..)

Comment: Didn't you mean `WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)` ?

Comment: the problem here is the quotes-  you are trying to compare the ID with the string '1,2,3' which is where it goes wrong. Remove the quotes and it will work

Comment: A single string containing commas is not at all the same thing as multiple strings (or ints, etc) *separated* by commas. SQL, in common with most languages, will not inspect the interior of the first, observe the commas and decide to treat it as if it were the second. Ideally, use a mechanism to properly pass multiple values to the database, or if that's not possible, search for `string split` and your RDBMS product to find plenty of solutions.

Comment: If you need to pass **multiple values** to a procedure to do some work, you should really look at [table-valued parameters](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/02/using-sql-servers-table-valued-parameters/) which are available in SQL Server 2008 and up

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert an `int` to varchar and back:

- `CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), ID)` makes `varchar(max)` from an `int` (`ID`)
- `CONVERT(INT, ...)` converts the result back to `int`

Since you have an `int` on the left of `IN`, RDBMS tries to convert each element of the list on the right side to `int` as well. Conversion of `'1,2,3'` fails, resulting in an error.

If you wish to convert `ID` to `varchar` and use `varchar` literals inside the `IN` list, drop the outer conversion:

```
DELETE FROM CM_OfflineMessages WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), ID) IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

Of course, there is no reason to do this, except as a learning exercise, because the end result is equivalent to a more efficient version without `CONVERT`:

```
DELETE FROM CM_OfflineMessages WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3)
```

**Edit:** You cannot pass a string `@ID` for a list of items. Use table-valued parameters instead ([how?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11102358/335858))

Comment: @bilal Unfortunately, you cannot do it like that: passing a single `@ID` for an entire array of things does not work. Depending on your RDBMS, you may be able to do it with a [table-typed parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11102358/335858), but generally you need multiple variables `@ID1`, `@ID2`, `@ID3` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use

```
DELETE FROM CM_OfflineMessages WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)
```

??

Comment: because I cannot append , in int from application end

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you don't have a Split/Parse function, here is an inline approach to split your string

**Example**

```
Delete From CM_OfflineMessages
 Where ID in (
                Select RetVal = B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'int')
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(@ID,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
              )
```