# Delete not working in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used the following command to execute the stored procedure, but the delete wont run. what is the problem?

```
exec sp_delete 'fruits', '''1.5'',''3.5'''
```

sp_delete

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_delete] 
@stock_type VARCHAR(255) 
,@weight VARCHAR(255)

AS 

IF @stock_type ='fruits'
BEGIN TRY
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblshop WHERE quantity='1' and weight in ( @weight))
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM tblshop WHERE quantity='1' and weight in ( @weight )
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

Comment: dont give procedures"sp_" as prefix http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: and here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669(v=sql.105).aspx#Naming%20Stored%20Procedures

Comment: SQL Server does not support macro substitution  ...  weight in ( @weight))

Comment: Also there is no need to first check if it exists an than delete it. Only records that exists will be deleted anyway.

Comment: You need to pass the different values as an array to the procedure, look at this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure

Comment: @JohnCappelletti i tried to put it in as `@str='delete from tblshop where weight in (' +@weight+')'` as well, and `exec @str` but it didnt work.

Comment: @whoami Was stock_type 'fruits' or 'AC'

Comment: yeah I would not expect the delete to happen if you pass 'AC' for the first parameter.

Comment: If you need to pass your data in as a comma delimited string then you can't use the parameter with the IN clause like that. In order to make this work, you will ned to first split your list into a temp table or use a table valued function that takes your lists and returns a table, one record per element. Once you have your @weight in a table format then you can simply use --> IN(SELECT Value FROM dbo.FunctionToTurnListIntoTable(@Weight))

Comment: @JohnCappelletti sorry, it was fruits. wrongly typed the parameters.

Comment: what version of sql server are you using ?

Comment: What is schema of table tblshop?

Answer (score 3):

Make it dynamic:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_delete] 
@stock_type VARCHAR(255) 
,@weight VARCHAR(255)
AS 
declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
IF @stock_type ='fruits'
BEGIN TRY
set @sql = '
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblshop WHERE quantity=''1'' and weight in ( ' + @weight + '))
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM tblshop WHERE quantity=''1'' and weight in ( ' + @weight + ' )
    END'
exec(@sql)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

and call it as [Update inline with comments]

```
exec sp_delete 'fruits', '1.5,3.5'
```

Comment: Why is this different from what they have already? You need to split the comma separated values into a table.

Comment: @WEI_DBA This works. Just don't pass the superfluous single quotes i.e: exec sp_delete 'fruits', '1.5,3.5'

Comment: @cloudsafe Query need not check IF EXISTS before DELETE statement, because DELETE will not delete any row if there is none. Otherwise, query has to delete it anyways. For the same reason, TRY CATCH is also not required here.

Comment: @cloudsafe. Ah. Didn't see the parms passing in. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to split @weight value into an array-like

and then `WHERE quantity='1' and weight in dbo.splitFunc(@weight)`

[How to pass an array into a SQL Server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure/11105413#11105413)