# How to pass an int column to a procedure which take an int parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure `MyProcedure` which needs an `int` as parameter, now I need to pass an int column from another table as parameter to the procedure. How can I write a statement to implement that? I can't use cursor in my code for some reasons. Below is my pseudo code. Thanks.

```
Create Procedure MyProcedure
  @i_input INT
AS
... ...

create table MyTable
(
    id int,
    otherdata float
)

exec MyProcedure (select id from MyTable)
```

Comment: Go for function because you can't run Procedure through DML/DDL

Comment: Not sure I understand - apart from returning the input parameter, what else are you doing with it? Are you intending to limit the result from MyResult? BTW, if you are intending to return the input parameter you need to add an @ symbol before the parameter. Is the commented out code only there to show your structure or are you intending to create the tables in the procedure?

Comment: what you want cannot be done like that, because your query will return more than one value and your procedure can only accept one value

Comment: maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure

Comment: I can't use function, becaues I have to call a procedure in my code, and i can't change the code of that procedure

Comment: If you have to execute a procedure for every row in a result set you are stuck using a cursor or while loop. Depending on the stored procedure perhaps it can be rewritten to receive a table valued parameter. This would be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Go for function because you can't run Procedure through DML/DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE MyResult
(
  id INT,
  results VARCHAR(MAX)
)
Go
CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction(@i_input INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
  SELECT @i_input AS ID, 'result1' AS results
)
Go
INSERT INTO MyResult SELECT * FROM MyFunction(1)
```

Comment: It is a poor suggestion to create a function named "MyProcedure". Your sample usage query is syntactically incorrect. It is also a poor suggestion to use an insert statement without specifying a column list. Nor does this help OP pass a value from a row in a table as the parameter to a function/procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
Create Procedure MyProcedure
  @i_input INT
AS
 ... ...

create table MyTable
(
   id int,
   otherdata float
)
Declare @temp_id int  
select @temp_id  =id from MyTable 

exec MyProcedure @temp_id
```