# How to pass array as parameter into SQL Server using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```
public bool AddEmployee(STUDENT_INFORMATION stuObj, string[] stuSubject) 
{
     string STUDENT_NAME = ""; 
     STUDENT_SUBJECT StuSubObj = new STUDENT_SUBJECT(); 

     var ArraParm = new string[stuSubject.Length]; 

     connection(); 

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UDSP_SAVE_STUDENT_INFO"); 
     cmd.Connection = con; 
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STU_ID", stuObj.STU_ID); 
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUDENT_NAME", stuObj.STUDENT_NAME); 
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUDENT_MOBILE_NUBER", stuObj.STUDENT_MOBILE_NUBER); 
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUDENT_EMAIL", stuObj.STUDENT_EMAIL); 
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUDENT_EMAIL", stuObj.STUDENT_EMAIL); 

     for (int k = 0; k < stuSubject.Length; k++) 
     {
         ArraParm[k] = string.Format("@{0}{1}", STUDENT_NAME, k); 
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(ArraParm[k], stuSubject[k]); 
     } 

     // return string.Join(", ", ArraParm);  
     //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SUB_NAME", stuSubject); 

     con.Open(); 
     int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
     con.Close(); 

     if (i > 1) 
     {
         foreach(var a in stuSubject) 
         { 
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SUB_NAME", StuSubObj.SUB_NAME); 

              con.Open(); 
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
              con.Close(); 
         } 

         return true; 
     } 
     else 
     { 
         return false; 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Create a custom user table type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017.  Basically passing a table/array to SQL.

Comment: @AmitKumar: this is the **minimum standard** how your next questions **must look like** to get any attention - I won't be redacting and reformatting your next questions any more! Learn how to do it yourself ! And also: you should give **some explanation**, too, of what you're trying to do (more than just a title) when dumping such a pile of code on the community ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an array into a SQL Server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure)

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If you are using 2016, you can pass and parse valid JSON objects.