# Split TEXT data type variable parameter in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

l had a parameter in my stored procedure that was `varchar(2000)`, my problem now is the characters being sent on the parameter have grown, the parameter now needs to handle 30 000 characters which are comma-separated. The biggest variable type that am now using (TEXT) is giving me issues in my where clause as below

Now using TEXT data type

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
    (@ArrayList TEXT =''  -- '93238128,93238131,93238130,93238133,93238132 ......
   )
```

then in my where clause

```
WHERE c.CLAIM_ID IN (SELECT Element FROM dbo.Split(@ArrayList ,',')) 
  AND @ArrayList <>'') OR @ArrayList =''
```

Getting this error :

> The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the not equal to operator.

Comment: ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Comment: Don't use `text`, use `varchar(max)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response . l have tried varchar(max) but it can not handle 30 000 characters

Comment: What about using [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure) ?

Comment: @Prince, `varchar(max)` can hold 2GB, 30.000 characters shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your input solution now working , Used arrays as suggested by @Cid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what l ended up using [Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11105413/3069202)! And it works great. Sending a table with one column to a stored procedure.