# How to pass and handle string array in azure Sql

Tags: sql, arrays, string, azure-sql-database

How to pass array of strings to stored proc in azure Sql? If not then do we have any alternative to string split to handle parameter passed like ‘123,34,46,44’ in stored proc in azure Sql? Here 123,34,46 are 3 different strings

I’m looking to get rid of string_split in stored proc for optimization

Comment: You could pass a json array or preferably a custom table data type.

Comment: Table valued parameters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Could you please go through this link and see if helps- similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure